# Pandas .loc taking a very long time

Tags: python, pandas, select, indexing

I have a 10 GB csv file with `170,000,000` rows and `23` columns that I read in to a dataframe as follows:

```
import pandas as pd 

d = pd.read_csv(f, dtype = {'tax_id': str})
```

I also have a list of strings with nearly 20,000 unique elements:

```
h = ['1123787', '3345634442', '2342345234', .... ]
```

I want to create a new column called `class` in the dataframe `d`. I want to assign `d['class'] = 'A'` whenever `d['tax_id']` has a value that is found in the list of strings `h`. Otherwise, I want `d['class'] = 'B'`.

The following code works very quickly on a 1% sample of my dataframe `d`:

```
d['class'] = 'B'
d.loc[d['tax_num'].isin(h), 'class'] = 'A'
```

However, on the complete dataframe `d`, this code takes over 48 hours (and counting) to run on a 32 core server in batch mode. I suspect that indexing with `loc` is slowing down the code, but I'm not sure what it could really be.

**In sum:** Is there a more efficient way of creating the `class` column?

Comment: Pandas is not capable of handling that much data. Look into `dask`.

Comment: Another question, are your tax numbers unique?

Comment: Not sure if this is any better, but try making the `h` list a second dataframe indexed on the `h` contents, then make `tax_num` the index on `d`, and the try a `join()`.

Comment: @coldspeed yup, my tax numbers in the list h are unique.

Comment: @sparc_spread thanks. I'll try that. Just to confirm, this should work even when the `tax_num` column in `d` has duplicate values, right?

Comment: Yes, pandas supports non-unique indexes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your tax numbers are unique, I would recommend setting `tax_num` to the index and then indexing on that. As it stands, you call `isin` which is a linear operation. However fast your machine is, it can't do a linear search on 170 million records in a reasonable amount of time.

```
df.set_index('tax_num', inplace=True) # df = df.set_index('tax_num')
df['class'] = 'B'
df.loc[h,  'class'] = 'A'
```

If you're still suffering from performance issues, I'd recommend switching to distributed processing with `dask`.

Comment: When I try this, I get the following error: 


`KeyError: "['352210820' '262816852' '097589434' ... '640789106' '593155203'\n '362812803'] not in index"`

I think this is because not all of the values in `h` are in `d['tax_num']`. Is there any way around this?

Comment: @svenkatesh you can do and intersection: h2 = df.index.intersection(h) and then index with h2.

Comment: @svenkatesh Oh, did it work? Out of curiosity, how long did it take after this change?

Comment: @coldspeed This worked perfectly, thanks! The three lines of code in your answer took 2.201 hours. The total run time (including file IO) took 3.671 hours.

Comment: @coldspeed I index with `h2 = set(h).intersection(d['tax_num'].unique())` instead of `df.index.intersection(h)`. Might be a semantic note, but wanted to point this out as the former is much faster.

Comment: @svenkatesh Interesting note; I will keep this in mind. `set.intersection` in general is very fast. By the way, if your tax_num is unique, then `d['tax_num'].unique()` is an unnecessary overhead :) `set(h).intersection(d['tax_num'])` should do, or equivalently, `set(h).intersection(d['tax_num'].tolist())`

Answer (score 1):

> "I also have a list of strings with nearly 20,000 unique elements"

Well, for starters, you should make that list a `set` if you are going to be using it for membership testing. `list` objects have linear time membership testing, `set` objects have very optimized constant-time performance for membership testing. That is the lowest hanging fruit here. So use

```
h = set(h) # convert list to set
d['class'] = 'B'
d.loc[d['tax_num'].isin(h), 'class'] = 'A'
```

Comment: My guess is using `numpy.isin()` should be much faster than the `set`. I tried it on small instance. `numpy.isin(df["column"], selection)` turned out to be 80microseconds vs 130 microseconds using `df["column"].isin(set(selection))`